# Is the shell : command portable?

Tags: bash, shell, null, zsh, csh

Is it recommended to use shell's `:` null command on supposedly portable scripts? Does it cope with csh, zsh, tcsh and whatever shell it may exist around there?

Comment: tcsh and csh have it (as well as the others). Most will accept non-significant arguments, but the `:` in csh refuses. But that's just another [black mark](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Comment: Incidentally, bash does not fully obey the POSIX spec for `:` unless its instantiated with `bash --posix`. For not `POSIXLY_STRICT` bash, `:` exists, but does not cause variable assignments to persist.

Comment: Does it even make sense to ask about csh when talking about shell portability?  csh is so different that attempting to make a script that does anything useful work in both csh and bourne shells seems futile.  (Writing a script that does anything useful in csh seems futile, but that's another story altogether.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It's the *standard* null utility. Reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/colon.html

Comment: While POSIX calls it a "utility" (which to me implies that it's external to the shell), it's actually a *builtin* in all the shells I checked (including the [Heirloom Bourne Shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html)) and it's not present in the filesystem (at least on mine).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson The word *utility* doesn't imply builtin-ness one way or the other. Bash and ksh say they're compliant with the Shell and Utilities portion of IEEE 1003.1, but they largely don't create additional executables beyond `bash` and `ksh` themselves, so to be compliant they must make those utilities builtins.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson [here's a bit more specific proof](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_14): *The special built-in utilities in this section need not be provided in a manner accessible via the exec family of functions defined in the System Interfaces volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001.* (Hat tip: pgas on Freenode/#bash)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the `:` built-in was already in the [Thompson shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_shell) — it's [documented](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/sh) for [Unix V6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_6_Unix) in 1975. That's older than such commonly-used features as the `PATH` variable, redirection of stderr with `2>`, and the `cd` command (then spelled `chdir`).

In the Thompson shell, `:` indicated a label for the [`goto`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/goto) command. If you never attempted to call `goto` on a line beginning with `:` , that line was effectively a comment. The [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), the ancestor of Bourne/POSIX shells as we know them, never had a `goto` that I know of, but retained `:` as a no-op command (it was already present in [Unix V7](http://cm.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/)).